# Pointer not displaying on my map

Tags: java, android, maps

I have a map that I want to put a marker on, but the marker isn't showing up. Here is my code:

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class MapDetailActivity extends MapActivity 
{
    private final static String TAG = MapDetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.map_view);


        // get longitude and latitude values from detail activity/object
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        float latitude = bundle.getFloat("uie.top25.seattle.latitude");
        float longitude = bundle.getFloat("uie.top25.seattle.longitude");

        Log.i(TAG, "Latitude that is set : " + latitude);
        Log.i(TAG, "Longitude that is set : " + longitude);
        // create longitude and latitude map points
        Double lat = latitude * 1E6;
        Double lon = longitude * 1E6;

        // create point on map
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(), lon.intValue());
        OverlayItem oi = new OverlayItem(point, null, null); 
        MapView mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.myMapView);
        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
        // set point on map
        mapController.animateTo(point);
        oi.setMarker(oi.getMarker(R.drawable.mm_20_red)); 
        // set zoom level
        mapController.setZoom(19);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
    {
        // No driving directions, so this method returns false
        return false;
    }

}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must add your item to map using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview this documentation Part-2

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Overlay to display a marker, read this: 
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay

If you couldn't be bothered reading all of that here's a ready to use tutorial:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/11/display-marker-on-mapview-using.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go through the documentation and examples, but the basic steps are:

1-Create your itemizedOverlay by extending the itemizedOverlay from google maps.

2-Add an overlay Item to your Itemized overlay, and set the marker or use the default one defined in the previous step.

3-Add the itemized overlay to the mapview overlays with:

```
mapview.getoverlays().add(myItemizedOverlay);
```

Just after you have add the overlay to the mapview overlays list, the overlay will be considered by mapview to be called for drawing on screen (calling the onDraw method)

good luck.